# Get Temp ASP.NET folder for application

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I'm trying to get a specific application base ASP.NET Temp folder. *I know we can use `HttpRuntime.CodegenDir` property to get the actual temp asp folder that the application is writing to*. Is there any way I can get location to the base folder for that application in C#? Example:

```
<server>\c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\<AppName>
```

Comment: @Christian.K i already mentioned that i HttpRuntime.CodegenDir gives me the required temp path but i was looking for is there any way that i can get the base folder of the application

Comment: Sorry, about that. I missed the "<AppName>" part in your "example".

Comment: @Christian.K Thats okay. Thank you for rectifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any other who stumble on this question,

I couldnt find any direct way to get it. the way i resolved this is to get executing assembly location using below line

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
```

And then get to the parent folder which is the application name recursively using

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);

        while (dir.Parent.Name != folderName)
        {
            dir = dir.Parent;
        }
        return dir.Parent.FullName;
```

which will give me the required path im looking for.